# Take the derivative of the parameter in an integral.

Tags: derivatives, definite-integrals

Consider two smooth functions $f(x)$, $g(x)$ defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $g$ has compact support. Easily, we have
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(ax)g(x)dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}a^{-d}f(x)g(a^{-1}x)dx,
$$
where $a>0$. Now take the derivative with respect to $a$, we get
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\ \frac{d}{da}(\text{LHS})\\&=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\sum_i x^i\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x^i}}(ax)g(x)dx\\&=\sum_i \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} a^{-1} x^i g(x) dx^1dx^2\cdots d_{x^i}(f(ax))\cdots dx^n\\
&=-\sum_i \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} a^{-1} f(ax)dx^1\cdots d_{x^i}(x^ig(x))\cdots dx^n\\&=-\sum_i \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} a^{-1}f(ax)[g(x)+x^i\frac{\partial{g}}{\partial{x^i}}(x)]dx\\&=-\sum_i\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}a^{-d-1}f(x)g(a^{-1}x)+a^{-d-2}f(x)x^i\frac{\partial{g}}{\partial{x^i}}(a^{-1}x)dx,
\end{aligned}
$$
however,
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\ \frac{d}{da}(\text{RHS})\\
&=\sum_i \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}-d a^{-d-1}f(x)g(a^{-1}x)-a^{-d-2}f(x) x^i\frac{\partial{g}}{\partial{x^i}}(a^{-1}x)dx.
\end{aligned}
$$
Since the equality hold for arbitrary $a>0$, it should keep right after taking derivative with respect to $a$. Would you tell me where is the problem here?